# SlideNavigationController access current controller from side menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mbprogresshud

I'm using SlideNavigationController https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu.

So, the thing is that in the side menu I have a button. When I tap on this button I want to show a loading view `MBProgressHUD` in the main controller. I tried adding the loading view to the main window, or `[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].view` and stuff like that, but the loading view always appears behind the main controller and above the side menu controller, so it is only visible when the side menu is opened.

Is there a way to add this view somehow, so it always appears above everything?

Answer (score 0):

Add it to `self.view.window`.

- [SlideNavigationController sharedInstance] - it is a
  UINavigationController
- main controller - it is rootController of [SlideNavigationController 
  sharedInstance]
- side menu - it is a UIView added to keyWindow

Thats why you have to add to keyWindow too.